# Count only and ordering controlled by sp parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have quite a complex query in a stored procedure that fetches a list of `id`s and then sould return different things controlled by two parameters:

```
@count_only [bit]
@order_type [tinyint]
```

So, if `@count_only` is `1` the query should simply return the result count, if not it should return the list of ids ordered depending on `@order_type`s value, eventually in need of additional joins:

F.ex., when `@order_type` is 1 one it should order by id, when it is 2 it should join the ids with a price table and order order by the matched price.

Currently I have 3 different `@order_type`s, but it could increase in future.
I want to return the result to my application as fast as possible (sure), it could result in a maximum of about 50K `varchar(50)` keys.

Is there any elegant way achieve this without writing the query multiple times?
I want to avoid something like this:

```
IF @count_only = 1 BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (mycomplexquery)
ELSE IF @order_type = 1 BEGIN
    SELECT [id] FROM (mycomplexquery) ORDER BY [id]
ELSE IF @order_type = 2 BEGIN
    SELECT [id] FROM (mycomplexquery)
    JOIN (prices) ON (...) ORDER BY [price]
END
```

I could create a table variable to store the result from `(mycomplexquery)`, but I fear that it might slow down the query to create the extra table, so I thought I'd ask whether anyone has a clever idea.

Comment: is it possible to consider stored procs inplace of those lengthy/complex queries ?

Comment: Further I recommend,that lengthy cmplex query to be inserted into a temp table first due to the fact that order types can grow in future  .Could you also help clarify if order types can be only one a time ,I mean it can be either 1 or 2 or 3

Comment: You can write your complex query as common table expression (with newtable as ()) and then apply your 'if' logic.
In my opinion there is no other way to do complex logic in t-sql. 
In contrary, I would suggest you to do business logic on application.

Comment: You could build a minimal query with dynamic sql based on the parameters.

Comment: Is it practical to make `(mycomplexquery)` a view? That would simplify creating a UDF to return the count and an SP to return the results. (It doesn't make much sense to have a single SP return a different _type_ of result based on the parameter values.) Since the `JOIN` is only required for one ordering you should either use two queries in an `IF`/`THEN` or use another method to avoid the evils of [parameter sniffing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/turgays/archive/2013/09/10/parameter-sniffing-problem-and-workarounds.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid messy code (like if/else structures within a query) in your SP, your best bet is to create two SPs.  One for the count only - and one for the list of IDs.  Or you could break them into totally separate queries and keep them in the same SP.  Having a CASE statement in your order by clause is no big deal for your second variable:

```
IF @count_only = 1
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (mycomplexquery)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT DISTINCT([id]) FROM (mycomplexquery)
        JOIN (prices) 
            ON (...) 
        ORDER BY 
            CASE WHEN @order_type = 1
                THEN [id]
                ELSE [price]
            END

    END
```